# About image rotation once element with specific id is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

Logo and elements from `ul` once clicked rotates image. By default image is already rotated by certain degrees, then on each click image rotates to necessary value.

So far I was using the following:

```
$("#objRotates").css('opacity','.2');
var value = 0;
var prev_value = 0;
$( "li" ).click(function() {
    var text=$(this).text();
    if(text==="text1"){value=0;}
    if(text==="text2"){value=33;}
    if(text==="text3"){value=66;}
    if(prev_value != value){
        $("#objRotates").animate({opacity:'1'});
        $("#objRotates").rotate({
            animateTo:value,
            easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo,
            center: ["25px", "150px"],
            callback: function(){$("#objRotates").animate({opacity:'0.2'});}
        });
    }
    prev_value = value;
});
```

Above code is the one that was used before, where images start position was 0 and its animation was triggered from link text.

Using jqueryRotate.js examples([here](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples))

**How do I change the code, so that images start position is certain degrees and animation starts if element with specific ID is clicked?**

Give at least clue..Cause for now, looking at my old code, I am lost. Thanks in advance.

SIMPLIFIED [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/407/)

Comment: I need a little clarification.  So, you want to click one specific link, and have the image rotate from an initial static predefined angle to another static predefined angle?  This is how the question sounds to me, so I just want to clarify before I start working on this problem.

Comment: Correct, you got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've created a couple of samples for you to check out.  The first one is very basic and I've simplified the code a little to make it easier to understand.  This one just uses completely static values and a static elementId for the event, which I'm pretty sure answers your question based on your response to my comment yesterday.  http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/594/

```
$("#elementId").click(function () {
    var startingAngle = 45;
    var endingAngle = 90;
    var elementToRotate = "img";
    $(elementToRotate).rotate({
        angle: startingAngle,
        animateTo: endingAngle
    });
});
```

But I wanted to give another example as well that would be dynamic and repeatable for multiple elements.  With the code above, you would have to copy/paste the same code over and over again if you want to perform this animation by clicking different elements.  Here's an alternative.  In this example, you set all of your parameters in the data attributes in the clickable element, then the function is completely repeatable, you only have to write it once.  Less code = everyone happy!  Here's the example:  http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/595/

```
//#region Default starting angles
$("#image1").rotate({ angle: 90 });
$("#image2").rotate({ angle: 20 });
//#endregion

$(".rotateAction").click(function () {
    //#region Optional parameter - used in the optional callback function
    var $self = $(this);
    //#endregion
    var startingAngle = Number($(this).attr("data-startingangle"));
    var endingAngle = Number($(this).attr("data-endingangle"));
    var elementToRotate = $(this).attr("data-elementtorotate");

    //#region If the current angle is the ending angle, reverse the animation - this can be removed if you want, I thought it may be cool to show some of the things you can do with this.
    var currentAngle = $(elementToRotate).getRotateAngle();
    if ( currentAngle[0] === endingAngle) {
        startingAngle = Number($(this).attr("data-endingangle"));
        endingAngle = Number($(this).attr("data-startingangle"));
    }
    //#endregion

    $(elementToRotate).rotate({
        angle: startingAngle,
        animateTo: endingAngle
        //#region This is optional - uncommenting this code would make the animation single-use only
        //, callback: function () { $self.off().removeClass("clickable"); }
        //#endregion
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.  If you need any other assistance, please let me know.

Comment: people by heart are helpful, thanks for looking into my question! But I feel stupid, cause this does not really help... here is fiddle I made http://jsfiddle.net/8c0go9gn/4/ jQuery does not work, unfortunately..
Image is horizontal, but I have to make it vertical by default(cannot do it in css3, because center point is made different than in js). Once its done, by clicking on color boxes image rotates to necessary angle.

Comment: made half working example http://jsfiddle.net/8c0go9gn/9/ where image rotates on first click, but then it doesnt react + by default is not rotated vertically + id which activates rotation can be in DIV or LI element. any ideas, please?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/8c0go9gn/18/  On the example in your first comment - you didn't include jQuery in jsfiddle, also, you're missing the closing parenthesis `)` after your closing brackets `}` on every click function - which is why it isn't working.  Side note:  good practice for cross-browser support and legacy support is to always start an id with a letter instead of a number.

Comment: One other note - setting `angle:` in the rotate options only moves it to that angle without animation, `animateTo:` animates it from its current position to the new angle.  I'm not sure what your desired result was, but I did change it to `animateTo`.  This could be changed back to `angle:`

Comment: thanks! my fault I didnt start with second example heheh. better than nothing. I appreciate your time